# Unable to remove previously assigned class with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-click function that filter list results. I am able to add a class with javascript to the clicked element but cannot remove it from the previously clicked elements. I was thinking I should iterate over the parentNode and then remove the class that I added. But, I am not getting the span elements in the childNodes list. How do I iterate over the other spans to remove the previously assigned class? Thank you.

console log of childNodes

```
NodeList(11) [text, comment, span.ng-binding.ng-scope, comment, span.ng-binding.ng-scope, comment, span.ng-binding.ng-scope, comment, span.ng-binding.ng-scope, comment, text]
```

// js function to assign class

```
$scope.updateTab = function(filterText,element) {
    var parentElem = element.parentNode;
    console.log(parentElem);
    var children = parentElem.childNodes;
    console.log(children);
    children.forEach(child, function(child){
            child.classList.remove('active-span');
    })
    element.classList.add("active-span");
    if(!filterText){
        $scope.searchText = filterText;
    } else {
        $scope.searchText = function(e) {
            return (filterText.indexOf(e.AssignedTo) !== -1);
        };
    }
};
```

html

```
<div class="col-4" id="tabs">
        <span ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-click="updateTab(tab.value,$event.currentTarget)">{{tab.label}}</span>
      </div>
```

Comment: You can loop through the `children` and use `classList.remove('active-span')`

Comment: I get a reference error saying child is not defined. I updated the function with the suggestion.

Comment: try removing first parameter (`child`) from  `children.forEach(child, function(child) {...})` function

Comment: See [Array.prototype.forEach usage on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)